# Combining fixed and fluid in a vertical layout

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="fluid-wrapper">
    <browser>
        <div class="navigation-bar">Navigation bar</div>
        <iframe class="browser-frame"></iframe>
    </browser>   
</div>
```

And Css

```
.fluid-wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
}

browser {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: hotpink;
}

.navigation-bar {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
}

.browser-frame {
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

The challenge is that i want the iframe i fit the `browser`-class while leaving space for the `navigation-bar`-class. I have tried using `calc()`but couldn't get it to work. As the CSS states, the `fluid-wrapper`is fluid. Therefore i cannot use fixed values.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asq24zbz/3/

Comment: use `border: none` for the iframe.

Comment: If you use `height: 100%;` for `.browser-frame` you should get your result.

Comment: But then it overflows because of the navigation-bar: https://jsfiddle.net/asq24zbz/1/

Comment: Aha! now I understand! good question. What exactly are you trying to do though? have 2 divs where 1 is navbar and the one below is iframe? both inside a container?

Comment: They should both be inside the `browser`-container. The `navigation-bar` should stay on top and the iframe should expand to the rest of the space of the `browser`-container...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asq24zbz/4/

Comment: Hah, but then the navigation-bar ain't fixed anyone...

Comment: What sort of browser support are you looking for? This is an instance for flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using CSS positioning?

Set the navigation to have an `absolute` position against the container which is `relative`. Then the iFrame is `relative` to the container with a `30px` top offset.

Will look like this:

```css
.fluid-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
browser {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.browser-frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  border: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-wrapper">
  <browser>
    <div class="navigation-bar">Navigation bar</div>
    <iframe class="browser-frame" src="http://www.wikipedia.com"></iframe>
  </browser>
</div>
```

As you can see, the Navigation bar is then fixed to the top of the containing div.

Comment: See my amended answer. Just needed box-sizing. For the proper version, just change the border from 1 to 0. :)